# generating a random sample from an exponential distribution in Stata

Tags: random, stata, exponential-distribution

I am trying to do a simulation in Stata with a random sample of 10000 for (i) the variable X with pdf
`f(x) = 2*x*exp(-x^2), X>0`, and (ii) `Y=X^2`
I worked out the cdf of F to be `1-exp(-x^2)`, so the inverse of F is `sqrt(-ln(1-u).`
I used the following code in Stata:

```
(1)  
 clear  
 set obs 10000  
 set seed 527665  
 gen u= runiform()  
 gen x= sqrt(-ln(1-u))  
 histogram x  
 summ x, detail  
(mean 0.88, sd 0.46)  
  

(2)  
clear  
set obs 10000  
set seed 527665  
gen u= runiform()  
gen x= (sqrt(-ln(1-u)))^2  
summ x, detail  
(mean 0.99, sd 0.99) 

(3)    
clear  
set obs 10000  
set seed 527665  
gen u= rexponential(1)  
gen x= 2*u*exp(-(u^2))  
summ x, detail  
(mean 0.49, sd 0.28)  

(4)
clear  
set obs 10000  
set seed 527665  
gen v= runiform()  
gen u=1/v  
gen x= 2*u*exp(-(u^2))  
histogram x  
summ x, detail  
(mean 0.22, sd 0.26)
```

My queries are: (i) (1) and (2) are based on the probability integral transformation, which I have come across but do not understand. If (1) and (2) are valid approaches, what is the intuition behind this, (ii) the output for (3) does not seem correct; I am not sure if I am applying the rexponential function correctly, and what is the scale parameter (there seems to be no explanation on this in stata help)  (iii) the output for (4) also does not seem correct, and I was wondering why this approach is flawed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what you worked out as distribution looks ok to me

If

PDF(x) = 2 x exp(-x<sup>2</sup>), x in [0...Infinity) then

CDF(x) = 1 - exp(-x<sup>2</sup>)

which means it is basically square root of exponentially distributed RV. [Exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) sampling is done
using `-ln(1-u)` or `-ln(u)`

I don't have Stata, just looking at the code

(1) looks ok, you sample exponential and get square root of it

(2) looks like you're sampling square root of exponential and immediately square it back.
You will get back exponential, I believe

(3) I don't know what it supposed to mean, exponent of squared exponentials? Should be

```
clear  
set obs 10000  
set seed 527665  
gen u = rexponential(1)  
gen x = sqrt(u)
summ x, detail
```

rexponential() is the same as -ln(1-runiform())

(4) Does not make sense. Exponent from squared uniform?

I quickly wrote simple Python code for illustration

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.random(100000) // uniform in [0...1)
xx = np.sqrt(-np.log(1.0-x)) // -log(1-x) is exponential, then square root

q = np.linspace(0.0, 3.0, 101)
z = 2.0*q*np.exp(-q*q)

n, bins, patches = plt.hist(xx, 50, density=True, facecolor='g', alpha=0.75)
plt.plot(q, z, 'r-')
plt.show()
```

with picture

[image]

Comment: For (4), if gen v= runiform()  generates random numbers between 0 and 1, will the inverse of v, 1/v, give random numbers between 0 and infinity

Comment: @Matt ok, and it still doesn't make sense. There is no division in your PDF, why do you want to divide uniformly distributed RVs? It should be square root of exponential, either via -ln(1-u) or rexponential() as I put in the code. You could draw histograms and compare them

Comment: @Matt I've updated the answer, added overlapping PDF on top of the histogram, everything looks good

Comment: `gen x = sqrt(rexponential(1))` is a smidgen more direct.

Comment: @NickCox sure, probably bit more efficient as well